# Angular2 Access Component Members in Observable Delegate?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm subscribing to a an rxjs ObservableSubject, and trying to reload an iframe when the event fires.  My observable delegate is firing but I can't seem to figure out how to access my component's attributes, they are all undefined.  here is some snippets:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tile-comp',
    templateUrl: './app/tiles/feature.html'
})

export class FeatureComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    dtUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('in ngOnInt');

    this._patientService.patientSubject.subscribe(
        currentPatientObs => { console.log('dt url ' + this.dtUrl); });

    }
}
```

I keep getting this written to the console: 'dt url undefined'.  The dtUrl is bound to the iframe's src so i was hoping to update the value in this observable delegate.

Thanks!

EDIT 1

---

Here is the full source code to the component:

```
import { Component, HostListener, HostBinding, OnInit, OnDestroy, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import {SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, RoutesRecognized, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { NavService } from '../layout/nav/nav.service';
import { NavigationItem} from '../model/NavigationItem';
import { SubNavigationItem, CTAButtonTarget} from '../model/SubNavigationItem';
import {OrderBy} from '../shared/orderBy';
import {PatientService} from '../patient/patient.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'tile-comp',
    templateUrl: './app/tiles/feature.html',
    pipes: [OrderBy], 
    providers: [NavService]
})

export class FeatureComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    selectedFeature: NavigationItem;
    selectedSubFeature: SubNavigationItem;

    featureQryParam: string;
    subfeatureQryParam: string;

    dtUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

    private routeParamObs: any;
    ctaButtons: SubNavigationItem[];

    constructor(private _navService: NavService, private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizationService, private _patientService: PatientService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.routeParamObs = this._route.params.subscribe(qp => {
            this.handleParamChange(qp);
        });

        this._patientService.patientSubject.subscribe(
            currentPatientObs => { console.log('dt url ' + this.dtUrl); });
    }

    getSelectedFeature() {

        this._navService.getSubNavItem(this.featureQryParam).subscribe(item => {
            this.selectedFeature = item;

            if (this.selectedFeature && this.selectedFeature.SubNavigation) {
                this.selectedFeature.SubNavigation.forEach(s => s.Href ? s.SanitizedUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(s.Href) : s.Href);

                if (this.subfeatureQryParam && this.subfeatureQryParam !== '') {
                    this.selectedSubFeature = this.selectedFeature.SubNavigation.find(sn => sn.SubFeature.toLocaleLowerCase() === this.subfeatureQryParam);
                } else {
                    this.selectedSubFeature = this.selectedFeature.SubNavigation.find(sn => sn.Order === 1);
                }

                this.getCTAButtons();

                this.dtUrl = this.selectedSubFeature.SanitizedUrl;
            }
        }); 
    }

    handleParamChange(params: any) {
        this.featureQryParam = params['feature'];
        this.subfeatureQryParam = (params['subFeature'] && params['subFeature'] !== '') ? params['subFeature'].toLocaleLowerCase() : '';
        this.getSelectedFeature();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routeParamObs.unsubscribe();
    }

    CTAButtonClick(ctaBtn: SubNavigationItem) {
        let ngRoute = [];
        ngRoute.push(ctaBtn.CTAButtonTarget.AngularRouteName);
        ctaBtn.CTAButtonTarget.AngularRouteParams.forEach(rParam => ngRoute.push(rParam));
        this._router.navigate(ngRoute);
    }

    //iterate over the subfeatures and grab all the cta buttons and load them into the ctaButtonTargets collection
    getCTAButtons() {
        this.ctaButtons = [];
        this.ctaButtons = this.selectedFeature.SubNavigation.filter(sn => sn.IsCTAButton === true);
        console.log('number of cta buttons: ' + this.ctaButtons.length);
        this.ctaButtons.forEach(btn => btn.CTAButtonTarget.Href ? btn.CTAButtonTarget.SanitizedHref = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(btn.CTAButtonTarget.Href) : btn.CTAButtonTarget.Href);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `this.dtUrl`?

Comment: Why do you think `_navService.getSubNavItem().subscribe(...)` is executed before `_patientService.patientSubject.subscribe(...)`? I didn't fully investigate all possible code paths because the code is too complex.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into issues in the past where variables refused to exist on the component when accessed via anonymous functions. The way I've dealt with it thus far is to create a method that specifically sets the data and call that from the subscribe. Such as:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.routeParamObs = this._route.params.subscribe(qp => {
        this.handleParamChange(qp);
    });

    this._patientService.patientSubject.subscribe(
        currentPatientObs => { this.performOperation(); });
}

performOperation(): void {
    console.log('dt url ' + this.dtUrl);
}
```

Not totally sure why this happens sometimes, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Perhaps you mean something like `catch(this.handleError)` (same for `map(...)` or all locations where method references are passed. This way inside `handleError()` `this.` is "broken" and doesn't point to the current component or service instance. If you pass it as `catch(this.handleError.bind(this)` or `catch((err) => this.handleError(err))` then `this.` is retained. I haven't seen anything like that in the code in the question.

Comment: We had a spot in our code where we were very specifically doing something like `this._patientService.patientSubject.subscribe(currentPatientObs => { this.dtUrl = currentPatienObs; });` and the `this.` was "broken" in the sense that we could not set anything on the component. The only way we could think to resolve it was to call a method that set the value for us, as displayed in my answer. This was a while ago (probably pre-RC?) so it might've changed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with how we are defining our subscription.  When i added an observable reference to the component I started to be able to access the Components member variables from in the observable delegate.  Here is what i did:

```
    export class FeatureComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    selectedFeature: NavigationItem;
    selectedSubFeature: SubNavigationItem;

    featureQryParam: string;
    subfeatureQryParam: string;

    dtUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

    private routeParamObs: any;
    private patientObs: any;
    ctaButtons: SubNavigationItem[];

    constructor(private _navService: NavService, private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizationService, private _patientService: PatientService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.routeParamObs = this._route.params.subscribe(qp => {
            this.handleParamChange(qp);
        });

        this.patientObs = this._patientService.patientSubject.subscribe(
            currentPatient => {

                console.log('dt url ' + this.dtUrl);
                this.refreshIframe(currentPatient);
            });
    }

    refreshIframe(pat:any) {
      console.log('dt url in method ' + this.dtUrl);
      console.log('pat: '+pat);
    }
```